# Why is systemd stuck at 100% inside my new Ubuntu LXC container?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, lxc, xubuntu

I am trying to create an LXC container with xubuntu desktop inside it. This is on a fresh Ubuntu 22.04 install with `sudo lxc launch images:ubuntu/22.04 workstation` executed to create the container, and then `apt install xubuntu-desktop` run inside the container.

The apt command hung around 75% and `top` showed `systemd` inside the container at 100% CPU, with `systemd-journal` hovering around 45% CPU.

`journalctl -f` inside the container showed log spam of:

`Condition check resulted in ACPI event daemon being skipped`

Over and over. Stopping the container and re-starting it caused the same issue (100% CPU, log spam, and any `systemctl` command hangs)

What's causing this and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 6):

The only relevant google search led me to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/OpenNebula/one/issues/5504) which said:

> IMHO the problem is more on the systemd side, as it doesn't handle correctly trigger events from one unit to another, if the target can't process the event. In this case, the source of the events is acpid.path which should kick into acpid service if directory /etc/acpi/events/ is not empty. In case of the containers, the acpid service is disabled by conditional check `ConditionVirtualization=!container` and can't run. This leads systemd into an infinite loop when the `acpid.path` generates again and again same trigger events and targeted `acpid.service` can never process it.

I resolved this my simply removing `/etc/acpi/events` (`sudo mv /etc/acpi/events /etc/acpi/events.bak`) and the problem went away instantly.

This is likely not the *right* fix, and I'll update my answer with a proper fix if I find more information -- but this resolved the immediate issue and allowed me to proceed with my xubuntu setup.

Comment: solve the same issue on upgrade from debian 10 to debian 11 on proxmox lxc container. Thanks.

Comment: note that `/etc/acpi/events` belongs to some pages: `dpkg -S /etc/acpi/events
-> acpi-support, acpid` on my machine. an update will bring back at least parts of this directory. but for now, my container is usable again